# In TeamsFx, how to construct ConversationReference without having a saved reference?

Tags: botframework, teams-toolkit

I am using TeamsFx SDK. I want to send a proactive message to a user. From reading documentation, it seems that recommended way is to listen to OnMembersAdded or OnMessageActivity and save the conversation reference to a persistent storage, so it can be later used for sending proactive messages.

But what if for whatever reason the conversation reference didn't get persisted? (let's say the network went down when a user was installing the app/bot into their Teams, so the conversation reference was never saved).

How would I recover from a situation when I need to send a proactive message but I don't have a reference to the conversation reference?

Is that possible to construct the conversation reference just by having the Aad ID of the user and the Bot/App Ids?

thank you